# Как правильно настроить Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, firebase, push-уведомления

Я пытаюсь настроить Firebase Cloud Messaging в своем приложении. Написал свой класс:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages
    // are handled
    // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data
    // messages are the type
    // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in
    // onMessageReceived when the app
    // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated
    // notification is displayed.
    // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages
    // containing both notification
    // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always
    // sends notification
    // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData());
}

/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
 * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
 */
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(token);
}

/**
 * Persist token to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
}

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 */
private void sendNotification(Map<String, String> data) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BaseActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = getString(R.string.notification_channel_id);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(data.get("title"))
                    .setContentText(data.get("message"))
                    .setSubText(data.get("subtitle"))
                    .setTicker(data.get("tickerText"))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Так же написал свой `php` файл с отправкой сообщений:

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAACTrwoSk:APA91bFMiujBNaZlg4GzmFq1965H-jmKVw1J1AmGMcV7KE5HyKz08NVjvfojflrMDcIEUVwhkeJWUaB3cUPFMgXJUwTam-Wye56i4pbD8kvMqSnnEi6W4GGRngOEy4gvXu53ooKRGzfL' );

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'       => $_POST['message'],
    'title'         => $_POST['title'],
    'subtitle'      => $_POST['subtitle'],
    'tickerText'    => $_POST['tickerText'],
    'vibrate'       => $_POST['vibrate'],
    'sound'         => $_POST['sound']
);

$msg = array_diff($msg, array(''));

$registrationIds = array( $_POST['registrationIds'] );

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($fields);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Возникли ряд вопросов. Лучше создавать уведомления через формы firebase или же писать свой отправщик? Если свой, то как отправить сообщение всем пользователям, а не только по токенам FCM? Также хотелось бы подробнее узнать как ведет себя уведомление, если приложение свернуто, а также если оно закрыто.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по документации https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple

> Firebase Cloud Messaging provides two ways to target a message to
> multiple devices:
>
> Topic messaging, which allows you to send a message to multiple
> devices that have opted in to a particular topic.
>
> Device group messaging, which allows you to send a message to multiple devices that
> belong to a group you define.

Поэтому можно подписывать все клиенты на один топик:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news")
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribe_failed);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

и отправлять сообщения таким образом:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
     "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
     "data": {
         "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
     }
}
```

Если приложение свернуто или закрыто, уведомление появится в статус-баре и в шторке уведомлений